# How to implement z-index and overflow

Tags: html, css, durandal

I am trying show "popup" windows that appear when the user hovers the cursor over a `div`. Everything is working fine, except when I added a scrollbar to my `div`. The CSS code to show the scrollbar is something like:

```
.scroll-menu {
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is an image before including the `.scroll-menu` class,
[image: no using scrollbar]

And here  is an image after including the CSS class.

[image: using scrollbar]

I found this article where the author says why z-index in my scenario:
http://www.satya-weblog.com/2012/01/css-z-index-not-working.html

Now, my question is:
    How can I solve this issue?
    Is there any way to get working z-index and overflow?

Comment: if possible provide us fiddle link

Comment: I would say to remove `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a z-index issue, but an overflow issue. Because you set the overflow to `hidden` any element visually sticking out of it's container, will be partially hidden - like in your screenshot. What you need to do is move your popup element outside of its container, the one that is set to `overflow-x:hidden`

so if your HTML currently looks like this:

```
<div class="scroll-menu">
    .... content ....
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

you want to change it to:

```
<div class="scroll-menu">
    .... content ....
</div>
<div class="popup"></div>
```

Comment: yes, this is a good way to solve it. The bad news (for me) is that i am using durandarl/widget in order to show this popup (where every element in my list has a "popup" widget associated to it. I think the only way to solve my issue is add some kind of pagination to my list and forget it this "scrollbar". Your answer was very useful since now i know that i don't have any chance with overflow and z-index.

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I believe this line may be causing your issue, since you're telling the containing div to truncate anything beyond it's borders.

Comment: it doesn't delete overflow-x while overflow-y is set